# Is multiple CAEAGLLayer available in iOS?

Tags: ios, multi-layer, caeagllayer

I get an OpenGL view by

```
+ (Class) layerClass
{
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}
```

and I want to add sublayer to it by

```
CAEAGLLayer *eaglLayer2 = [[CAEAGLLayer alloc] init];
[self.layer addSubLayer:eaglLayer2];
```

The purpose to think this is that I want to draw different thing on different layer so that I can remove something by simply call removeSubLayer:enter code here.

Is it available?